# Generating invoice email using Webhook in Stripe and Mailchimp

Tags: stripe-payments, mailchimp, webhooks, invoice

Can anyone please tell me (or point me in the direction) how to generate an invoice email using webhook api in stripe with the mailchimp account?

Comment: Invoices (and receipts) are really not a good fit for MailChimp. Rather, you should look into Mandrill, a transactional email service from the same folks who make MailChimp.

Comment: @TooMuchPete Hi Pete, thanks or the reply. Lets say I have a mandrill account, then how do I generate a invoice email (using stripe in this instance)?

Comment: Well, it sounds like there are some details that are missing to answer that question really specifically, but the general answer is that you would create a web-service to receive the webhook. That service would then send an email that you've designed when that service gets notified by stripe of a new payment.

For more specific help, we'll need to know more about what language you're using, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do that directly because you can't create a MailChimp endpoint which receives data through the web. You need an intermediary layer in between Stripe and MailChimp, which receives data from Stripe, validates the data, converts the data according to your needs, and using MailChimp API sends it to MailChimp to be sent out as an email. But an easier approach will be (in my opinion) creating an in-house solution for sending out emails instead of using MailChimp.